# Distribution function that has an infinite number of jumps in $ [0,1] $.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Construct a distribution function that has an infinite number of jumps in $ [0,1] $.

Hello, I need help to build this distribution function, I know that for it to comply with being a distribution it must meet the limits in $ - \infty $ and in $ \infty $
In addition to the monotony and that it is continuous on the right.
But I have problems with the construction, I also know that the jumps must be countable, this could be seen from the partitions?

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is random variable taking value $1,\frac 1 2,\frac 1 3,...$ such that $P(X=\frac  1n)=\frac 1{2^{n}}$ then $F_X$ has jumps at each of the points $\frac  1 n$. An explicit definition of $F_X$ is $F_X(x)=\sum\limits_{n: \frac 1 n \leq x} \frac 1 {2^{n}}$.

Comment: But the limit of n in $ - \ infty $ does not comply with being 0, is it?

Comment: @ChristianTrinajero $F_X(x)=0$ for all $x <0$.

Comment: Let me restate the definition in words: $F_X(x)$ is the sum of the numbers $\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ where $n$ is restricted to those positive integers that satisfy $\frac  1n \leq x$. If ther are no such intergers then $F_X(x)$ is defined as $0$.@ChristianTrinajero